# STM8 Programming Error using STVD

Tags: microcontroller, error, stm8

[image: Schematic]

I am using a STM8S105C6T6 in one of my application and I am facing problem while programming it.

**Software used:** STVD version 4.3.12

**Compiler:** Cosmic CXSTM8 Special Edition 4.5.1 (Free 1yr License version)

I have build my application and when I click on ''start Debug'' in STVD, below error comes

1. **Debug Session:**

> Starting debug session...
>
> -> Emulator reset (usb://usb)...
>
> done.
>
> Opening application
> C:\Users\Micro\Desktop\STM8\STM8S105\led\Debug\led.elf...
>
> -> failed to download application: error: swim prog error [42004]:
> memory write error
>
> Application closed.
>
> Debug session closed.

2. **Using Light Programmer**
   When I am Trying to Program using STVD in-built Programmer, it is showing below error:

> ''STVD > Tools > Programmer'' or using STVP.
>
> Programming...
>
> PROGRAM MEMORY:
>
> Blank Check not feasible Programming Error : Programming failed Error
> : Problem while trying to Reset swim and device. Apply a Power On
> Reset

The interesting thing is, sometimes the MCU is getting programmed (LEDs are blinking as per requirement) but the software is showing same error message as above.

I don't understand why I am getting this error. My hardware connection and the SWIM communication are OK because I am able to program my other MCU i.e. STM8103F3P6 bare minimum blue board using same settings in STVD

How can I solve this error ?

Comment: do you use swim pin in your application as a gpio? and what is connected externally to your nrst pin? a schematic would help.

Comment: Hi Tirdad, No I have not used  SWIM pin as GPIO. NRST Pin is pulled up to 5V with 10K ohm resistor and a capacitor of value 10nF is connected in between NRST and Ground pin. I have tried capacitor of 1nf, 10 nf, 100nf, 1uF, 10uF. With larger value of cap it is not working while with smaller value I am able to program 1 out of 100 times. It seems like the problem is with the reset circuitry only. Let me know how can I share the schematic with you as I am not able to upload any kind of file here @TirdadSadriNejad

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad can you please help?

Comment: place a schematic in the question. it would be easier to track the problem. what's the value of the capacitor connected to VCAP pin of stm8 ?

Comment: I just changed the capacitors with crystal oscillator and cap@ VCAP from SMD to box type polyester cap, and now I am able to program the MCU (normal LED blink Code 1KB). Still I am facing issue while uploading my actual application program which is 30KB